# JSON foreach only gets first result out of an array

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file (test.json) which is

```
{
    "fruit": [{
        "id": 364823,
        "name": "Lemon",
        "amount": [33],
        "profile": "http://google.com",
        "buyid": 5
    }, {
        "id": 367851,
        "name": "Orange",
        "amount": [69, 95, 166],
        "profile": "http://google.com",
        "buyid": 3
    },{
        "id": 35647,
        "name": "Apple",
        "amount": [77, 43],
        "profile": "http://google.com",
        "buyid": 31
    } ]
}
```

then i have my PHP script to echo

```
$url="test.json";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($json, true);
    $names = array();
    foreach($json['fruit'][0]['amount'] as $val) 
{
    echo $val . " <br> ";
}
```

Which returns

```
33
```

how can i get it to return?

```
33
69 95 166
77 43
```

i can get it to work with the others like *id*,*profile* and *buyid* but not this array

Comment: Why the "javascript" tag? Regarding your requirement, wouldn't you need a nested loop?

Comment: `['fruit'][0]['amount']` array has only one element `"amount": [33]`

Comment: either add another `foreach` dimension pointing to `amount` or implode on the first level

Comment: You are going to iterate over all the fruit and then iterate over ``amount``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($json['fruit'] as $fruit){
    echo implode(' ',$fruit['amount']);
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/emvgE)

Comment: You're welcome :-)  If it solves your problem, don't forget to select this answer.